# How to vary symbology by length and width

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology

I help maintain a steam map in ArcGIS Pro. Part of the features in the map, alongside lines for steam and steam condensate are the steam vaults. The steam vaults are depicted as points. Of course, in real life, the vaults vary in shape and size. I was wondering what options exist to show these features as symbology. I’m also open to hear if varying these features in symbology is less efficient than simply using polylines to map the outlines of the vaults.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by varying the size of the steam vault symbology? Are you just trying to show their relative volume, in which case varying the size of the symbol, say a circle, relative to volume would work. Or are you trying to show a literal representation of the vault size and shape, in which case you would want to create a polygon layer. Or yet some other goal?

Comment: I think my original goal was to show literal size of the vault. But I’d also be open to varying the symbology based on their relative area - but thanks! I hadn’t thought of trying to represent them by volume, that’s a good idea. I don’t technically have authority to add layers, so I was going to suggest to the GIS technician a way to use an existing layer to represent vault size.